# Combining Grep and a For-Loop to Construct A Matrix (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, matrix

I have a huge list of small data frames which I would like to meaningfully combine into one, however the logic around how to do so escapes me.

For instance, if I have a list of data frames that look something like this albeit with far more files, many of which I do not want in my data frame:

```
MyList = c("AthosVersusAthos.csv", "AthosVerusPorthos.csv", "AthosVersusAramis.csv", "PorthosVerusAthos.csv", "PorthosVersusPorthos.csv", "PorthosVersusAramis.csv", "AramisVersusAthos.csv", "AramisVersusPorthos.csv", "AramisVerusPothos.csv", "BobVersusMary.csv", "LostCities.txt")
```

What I want is to assemble these into one large data frame. Which would look like this.

```
                   |                    |
 AthosVersusAthos  | PorthosVersusAthos | AramisVersusAthos
                   |                    |
 ------------------------------------------------------
                   |                    |
 AthosVerusPorthos | PothosVersusPorthos| AramisVersusPorthos
                   |                    |
 ------------------------------------------------------
                   |                    |
 AthosVersusAramis | PorthosVersusAramis| AramisVersusAramis
                   |                    |
```

Or perhaps more correctly (with sample numbers in only one portion of the matrix):

```
           |       Athos      |      Porthos       |    Aramis
    -------|------------------------------------------------------
           | 10     9      5  |                    |
    Athos  | 2      10     4  |                    | 
           | 3      0      10 |                    |
    -------|------------------------------------------------------
           |                  |                    |
   Porthos |                  |                    |                  
           |                  |                    |
    -------|------------------------------------------------------
           |                  |                    |
   Aramis  |                  |                    |                  
           |                  |                    |
    -------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I have managed so far is:

```
Musketeers = c("Athos", "Porthos", "Aramis")

  for(i in 1:length(Musketeers)) {
    for(j in 1:length(Musketeers)) {

    CombinedMatrix <- cbind (

      rbind(MyList[grep(paste0("^(", Musketeers[i],
      ")(?=.*Versus[", Musketeers[j], "]"), names(MyList),
      value = T, perl=T)])

  )
 }
}
```

What I was trying to do was combine my `grep` command (quite importnant given the number of files and specificity with which I need to select them) and then combine `rbind` and `cbind` so that the rows and the columns of the matrix are meaningfully concatenated.

My general plan was to merge all the data frames starting with 'Athos' into one column, and doing this once again for data frames starting with 'Porthos' and 'Aramis', and then combine those three columns, row-wise into a final dataframe.

I know I'm quite far off but I can't quite get my head around where to start.

Edit: @PierreGramme generated a useful model data set which I will add below seeing as I imagine it would have been useful to provide it originally.

```
Musketeers = c("Athos", "Porthos", "Aramis")
MyList = c("AthosVersusAthos.csv", "AthosVersusPorthos.csv", "AthosVersusAramis.csv", 
                    "PorthosVersusAthos.csv", "PorthosVersusPorthos.csv", "PorthosVersusAramis.csv", 
                    "AramisVersusAthos.csv", "AramisVersusPorthos.csv", "AramisVersusAramis.csv",
                    "BobVersusMary.csv", "LostCities.txt")
MyList = lapply(setNames(nm=MyList), function(x) matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3, dimnames=list(c("a","b","c"), c("x","y","z"))) )
```

Comment: Would you like to keep the exact display or different display formats are welcome?

Comment: If you are referring to the order of the 'Musketeers' along the x and y-axis of the final data frame, I would like to preserve them as they are in my 'Musketeers' array. This is not only to help me but also ensure the layout of data is consistent when I plot it.

Comment: I mean the display, are you simply interested in the result or would like to have `|---` style kept?

Comment: Please try to be more precise: is `MyPLList` a named list of data frames, whose names are `MyList`? What is the difference between `ConditionsAbbr` and `Musketeers`?

Comment: Oh, I only used those as graphical representations of the final object I would like to achieve? Perhaps I should have created various numerical matrices but I thought that would clutter the question. As long as the order is correct in the actual object/data frame so that I can look at it if I must and plot it in a manner that is easily interpretable for humans, I don't care how it displays in a given window.

Comment: @PierreGramme Sorry I, I hadn't homogenised the variable names in my example. It's fixed now.

Comment: Too many typos... Pathos? Porthos? Pothos?  Musketters? Musketeers?  Your definition of MyList is not syntactically correct and is not used afterwards... And we still have no idea of the content of MyPLList. That's a lot of extra and annoying difficulties that you should fix yourself

Comment: @PierreGramme Yes, there were some typos and a missing quotation mark. I have no problem fixing those once I have found them. However there is no MyPLList that I can see, that was removed when I fixed the variable names. As for my list, how do I make it syntactically correct or were you referring to the missing quotation mark? Additionally, 'MyList' is used in my for-loop. Whilst I'm sorry that typos are annoying, you are flagging mistakes for a second time after they have already been removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a reproducible example. Is it faithful? If so, I will add code to answer

```
Musketeers = c("Athos", "Pothos", "Aramis")
MyList = c("AthosVersusAthos.csv", "AthosVersusPothos.csv", "AthosVersusAramis.csv", 
                    "PothosVersusAthos.csv", "PothosVersusPothos.csv", "PothosVersusAramis.csv", 
                    "AramisVersusAthos.csv", "AramisVersusPothos.csv", "AramisVersusAramis.csv",
                    "BobVersusMary.csv", "LostCities.txt")
MyList = lapply(setNames(nm=MyList), function(x) matrix(rnorm(9), nrow=3, dimnames=list(c("a","b","c"), c("x","y","z"))) )
```

And then is it correct that you would like to concatenate 9 of these matrices into your combined matrix shaped as you described?

**Edit:**
Then the code solving your problem:

```
# Helper function to extract the relevant portion of MyList and rbind() it
makeColumns = function(n){
    re = paste0("^",n,"Versus")
    sublist = MyList[grep(re, names(MyList))]
    names(sublist) = sub(re, "", sub("\\.csv$","", names(sublist)))

    # Make sure sublist is sorted correctly and contains info on all musketeers
    sublist = sublist[Musketeers]

    # Change row and col names so that they are unique in the final result
    sublist = lapply(names(sublist), function(m) {
        res = sublist[[m]]
        rownames(res) = paste0(m,"_",rownames(res))
        colnames(res) = paste0(n,"_",colnames(res))
        res
    })

    do.call(rbind, sublist)
}

lColumns = lapply(setNames(nm=Musketeers), makeColumns)
CombinedMatrix = do.call(cbind, lColumns)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a really nice way to achieve what I wanted. Much more sophisticated than what I was building towards.